# Change line shape to aggregated plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm attempting to make a plot of net sentiment score by genre over time. I currently have a line plot that works, but I'd like to make each genre a different color/shape. However, I have about 12 different genres and I'd prefer to not manually assign a color/shape to each genre. Is there a way for matplotlib to dynamically assign a unique combination to each genre? Here's my current code.

```
# plot net sentiment per year by genre
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
genre_known.groupby(['year', 'genre']).mean()['net_sentiment'].unstack().plot(ax=ax)
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Sentiment')
plt.title('Sentiment by Year')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a styling dictionary like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df_tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
style_dic = {k:v for k,v in zip(df_tips['day'].unique(),['ro-','b^-','gs-','m+-'])}
df_tips.groupby(['sex','day'])['total_bill'].mean().unstack().plot(ax=ax, style=style_dic);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @carousallie Did this answer help you?